# Applications types supported by Azure WebApp as Container

Tags: azure

I want to migrate existing workloads to Azure cloud in Web App as Container.  As per my understanding the Pass offering  has inbuilt Tomtcat and IIS webserver images of all versions and supports following application types to run in Java/.NET stack:

Linux container:

1. ASP.NET Core
2. Java/Tomcat

Windows Container

1. Classic ASP
2. ASP.NET Web Forms (any version)
3. ASP.NET MVC (any version)

Does WebApp as Container supports hosting of any other application types in Java/.NET? If not what would the approach be to host an existing Java application which is deployed in WebSphere server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you want to use azure web for containers, then you can deploy any type of app, just package the required dependencies in your dockerfile.

If you specifically want to deploy JAVA application, then create war instead of a jar, and then package it using dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have an JAVA application which runs in WebSphere application server. Would that be enough if I just upload war files for the application in WebApp as Container? Does Azure WebApp as Contaner Service has inbuilt Webshere Server image? Otherwise how would it run the application?